# Manually setting timestamp format with user defined schema in QuestDB import

Tags: questdb

I want to import some data with `curl` to the rest endpoint. I need to use a user defined schema [described in the docs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest/#user-defined-schema), but I have some issues with specifying timestamp format.

This is a minimal example of what I'm sending:

```sh
curl -i \
-F schema='[{"name":"ts", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"},{"name":"instance_id", "type": "STRING"}]' \
-F data=@log_out.csv \
http://localhost:9000/imp
```

Columns are being imported correctly, but the timestamp column looks broken:

| ts | instance_id |
| --- | --- |
| `NULL` | EU-1XX |
| `NULL` | EU-1XX |
| `NULL` | EU-2XX |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the user-defined schema with TIMESTAMP types, you should be using `pattern` instead of format in the schema query parameter, i.e.:

```sh
curl -i \
-F schema='[{"name":"ts", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "pattern": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"},{"name":"instance_id", "type": "STRING"}]' \
-F data=@log_out.csv \
http://localhost:9000/imp
```